# Android generate APK issue

Tags: java, android, java-11

android studio appear this issue when trying to generate singed APK

> Task :app:dexguardApkRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardApkRelease'.

> Process 'command '/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.5/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

any advise ?

trying to generate signed APK

Comment: Is dex enabled in your build.gradle?

Comment: what you mean with dex ? and how to enable it ?

Answer (score 0):

01 - file-invalidate cache and restart

02 - Clean project and Rebuild

03 - now check your internet is working fine poxy setting.

04- then try.

#Android_studio